# What operations preserve pseudo concavity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What operations preserve pseudo concavity? For instance, is the sum of two pseudo concave function pseudo concave (like for concavity)? Or is the product of two pseudo concave function pseudo concave (like for log concavity)? The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoconvex_function) has very little information and I cannot find a good reference on this topic.